# Checking if an argument is null in commander?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

Using [commander.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) to create a CLI and I have a statement like this:

```
 cli.
 command('serve').
 alias('s').
 description('Create a new project').
 action((target) => {
    console.log("TARGET IS: ", target) ....
```

The parameter `target` logs as value regardless of whether a value is provided to the command.  How do we check whether the `target` argument is null?  This is what is logged for the value of target when no value is passed to the command:

```
        TARGET IS:  Command {
        commands: [],
        options: [],
        _execs: {},
        _allowUnknownOption: false,
        _args: [],
        _name: 'serve',
        _noHelp: false,
        parent: 
        Command {
            commands: 
            [ [Command],
                [Command],
                [Command],
                [Command],
                [Command],
                [Command],
                [Circular],
                [Command] ],
            options: [ [Option] ],
            _execs: {},
            _allowUnknownOption: false,
            _args: [],
            _name: 'sfc',
            Command: { [Function: Command] super_: [Function] },
            Option: [Function: Option],
            _version: '1.0.0',
            _versionOptionName: 'version',
            _events: 
            { 'option:version': [Function],
                'command:new': [Function: listener],
                'command:n': [Function: listener],
                'command:clean': [Function: listener],
                'command:c': [Function: listener],
                'command:build:main:css': [Function: listener],
                'command:bmc': [Function: listener],
                'command:build:test:css': [Function: listener],
                'command:btc': [Function: listener],
                'command:build': [Function: listener],
                'command:b': [Function: listener],
                'command:test:html': [Function: listener],
                'command:t': [Function: listener],
                'command:serve': [Function: listener],
                'command:s': [Function: listener],
                'command:dist': [Function: listener],
                'command:d': [Function: listener] },
            _eventsCount: 17,
            _description: 'SuperflyCSS Command Line Interface',
            _argsDescription: undefined,
            rawArgs: [ '/usr/bin/node', '/home/ole/.npm-packages/bin/sfc', 'serve' ],
            args: [ [Circular] ] },
        _alias: 's',
        _description: 'Serve project',
        _argsDescription: undefined }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a runnable snippet of the **`!` (logical NOT) operator** in use to check wether a variable is null (or false).

```js
   var nullVar = null;
if(!nullVar){alert("nullVar is null (or false)")}
```

So you can see that it can be easily applied to your case.

Comment: Thanks - It turns out that if the argument (Which is optional in this case) is null, commander replaces it with its own meta argument, so we can't do a normal null or false check ... I'll show my implementation in another answer.

Comment: @Ole you could use `typeof` if you know your `target` is going to be a sepcific type

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if the argument (Which is optional in this case) is null, commander replaces it with its own meta argument, so we can't do a normal null or undefined check.  Here's how I implemented the check:

```
cli.
command('serve').
alias('s').
description('Serve project').
action((target) => {

    let serve = null;
    if (typeof target === 'string' || target instanceof String) {
        serve = target;
    }
    else {
        serve = PLI.target.test.html;
    }
```

For all source code [see here](https://github.com/superflycss/cli)